# Amplify v6 not returning token to angular from cognito hosted ui

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm on Angular 15 and I updated from aws-amplify v5 to v6. I had to restructure some of the calls since it was a breaking change and I have everything connected I thought, but my app doesn't authenticate anymore. I think it has something to do with my auth service because that's the only change from when it was working. I'm using the Cognito Hosted UI currently.

Here's my auth service currently.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { fetchAuthSession, getCurrentUser, signOut } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolId: environment.cognito.userPoolId,
      userPoolClientId: environment.cognito.appClientId,
      signUpVerificationMethod: 'code',
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          domain: 'my-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
          scopes: [
            'email',
            'profile',
            'openid',
            'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin',
          ],
          redirectSignIn: [environment.redirectUrl],
          redirectSignOut: ['http://localhost:4200/'],
          responseType: 'code',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
const currentConfig = Amplify.getConfig();
console.log('currentConfig', currentConfig);

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  authIsLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  authDidFail = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authStatusChanged = new Subject<boolean>();
  public loggedIn = false;

  async getAuthenticatedUser() {
    try {
      const { username, userId, signInDetails } = await getCurrentUser();

      console.log(`The username: ${username}`);

      console.log(`The userId: ${userId}`);

      console.log(`The signInDetails: ${signInDetails}`);
      return signInDetails;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  }

  async getRefreshedAuthenticatedUser() {
    try {
      const { accessToken, idToken } = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens ?? {};
      return { accessToken, idToken };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return null;
    }
  }

  async logout() {
    try {
      await signOut();
      this.authStatusChanged.next(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = await this.getAuthenticatedUser();
    console.log('USERTIME', user);
    return !!user;
  }
}
```

In addition I set up a lambda preAuth and postAuth cognito trigger functions to make sure those steps happen and both got an event. So it's just amplify not giving me my token for some reason. Also on my app in amplify v5 the localStorage had these tokens there, but they aren't there in v6

[image]

Here's the 302 redirect from cognito hosted UI

```
HTTP/2 302 
date: Mon, 20 Nov 2023 23:51:41 GMT
content-length: 0
location: http://localhost:4200/redirect/?code=0274cb71-2add-4bff-8f8f-9d004ea14438
content-security-policy-report-only: script-src https://d3oia8etllorh5.cloudfront.net https://my-view-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com; style-src https://d3oia8etllorh5.cloudfront.net https://my-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com; img-src https://placeholder.cloudfront.net https://my-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com; report-uri https://my-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/cspreport
x-amz-cognito-request-id: dsfssd-ed22-4d41-a4cf-45add22e55fa
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
XSRF-TOKEN=2bf2bb29-e8b7-40ff-9914-7b41a7ac3d18; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
cognito="H4sIAAAAAAAAAAH9AAL/XiELDZtKtGVzEjYV00NzW5p9zaydExOStPySiR1SBPOyKnEgsl4e53j3MTLptV8bCJo8elZBNSGu/jvy3TtJB70Z3sqYlrbUYp0u5C2y0pj5GMoRgzWGVCHdq1LRqeA1EwuVNaIcoJk1wvTm6ZUl20fK16XtrGg1VZ7eL1r+s/YOEi/43vO+NlGtFw6AHArhlhwDGRtEMDWY7PFCqfsTwIUnefTSCXbikC6gDgOn5Q+iOx8Ds9ZD5u4KI3Jj3Q4TiwbNLYTCAsdOyPEL25cJyLVueuQLV/fmUQ+U1LL58TyE8b0W2+kSY0/6UISpH5WyrOfsQUHhoUbauvZ+vCbUQgj9AAAA.H4sIAAAAAAAAAMtjLvQ8wJZutipCkXOd1e2P33qfWLqEXvth1xv8J7vc4yQAfSRTdSAAAAA=.4"; Version=1; Domain=my-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com; Max-Age=3600; Expires=Tue, 21-Nov-2023 00:51:41 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: DENY
server: Server
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Errors I see

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): UserUnAuthenticatedException: User needs to be authenticated to call this API.`
That's from getCurrentUser().

Comment: Same error in React using Amplify V6. Any solution???

Comment: I get this log in the server,  recoverySuggestion: 'Sign in before calling this API again.',
 but no changes after resigning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, to fix the error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): UserUnAuthenticatedException: User needs to be authenticated to call this API` you first need to log in. However, if you are using Cognito Hosted UI along with Amplify v6, you need to call the signInWithRedirect() method.

Something like this:

```js
import { signInWithRedirect } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

constructor() {
    this.signIn;
}

public async signIn(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        await signInWithRedirect();
    } catch (err) {
        this.loggerService.error(err);
    }
}
```

After that, you can access and call getCurrentUser(); ... etc.

Comment: You are awesome! This worked. I was starting to think amplify v6 was a broken product.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `ssr` option for Next.js =>

```
Amplify.configure(
      {
        Auth: {
          Cognito: {....},
          },
        }
      },
      { ssr: true },
    );
```

Comment: Welcome - can you please add supporting evidence as to why this option needs to be provided?

Comment: https://docs.amplify.aws/angular/build-a-backend/server-side-rendering/#pageMain

Comment: I'm not using Next.js or Angular SSR for this project. This is Angular 15.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Next.js 14 when trying to run `getCurrentUser()` on the server-side. The issue in my case was that the sign in was made using another user pool client (web/app client) than the client that I was using to run `getCurrentUser()`.

The solution was to use the same user pool client (web/app client) for the sign in action and to retrieve the current user.

Comment: The user pool id and app client id haven't changed so I'm not so sure that's the issue. Also since the lambda triggers are generating cloudwatch logs that tells me that it's hitting the user pool with the lambda triggers set up.